# How to escape column names in a dynamic list of column in Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have the following statement that dynamically generates a list of columns to be used in a join condition.
This works ok but fails for columns that have special characters. For example a column named: **ABC#XYZ** or columns with space in between.
I know back ticks can be used in an SQL statement but in a regular python statement as below where will I be inserting the back tick?

```
col_list_cond = [" & (  regexp_replace( file_df_new."+ c +",' ','') != regexp_replace(table_df_new."+ c +",' ','')   )" for c in col_list]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with python [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) and add ` before and after the variable c:

```
new_col_list = [f"`{col}`" if '#' in col else col for col in col_list]
```

Then use this new list below:

```
col_list_cond = [" & (  regexp_replace( file_df_new."+ c +",' ','') != regexp_replace(table_df_new."+ c +",' ','')   )" for c in new_col_list]
```